# In mousekeyhook, What does the "ext' after the mouse hooks mean?

Tags: c#, mousekeyhook

For example, there is IKeyboardMouseEvent.MouseDown and IKeyboardMouseEvent.MouseDownExt. What is the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It means Extended.

The windows `MouseEventArgs` class does not contain a Handled property and the extended `MouseEventExtArgs` class does.  `e.Handled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

These events use args and handlers which present "extended" data/capabilities.

In this case, one difference would be that they expose a Handled event.

I can't seem to find official docs for these, I'm curious where they even originate from as I've never come across them.  It's possible with more information someone might be uncover another resource.  Are these vanilla .NET?

Your best bet might be to either either browse the symbols or create an instance of each and peruse them in the debugger.

Without knowing the context, I have to guess that the resource I've found on them is related. If so, I would suggest using the version with more capabilities.

[Source](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/documentation)